# Tips to enhance javascript code

Tags: javascript, css-transforms

Was doing a nice-dropping navigation using css3 transforms.
Also written some javascript for this purpose.

But unfortunately it looks a bit untidy.
Would you guys please give me some tips to optimize javascript code.

The pen `-->` http://codepen.io/rokki_balboa/pen/doOqqv?editors=001

```
var bar = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    bar.onclick = function() {

            var delayIn = 0;
            var delayOut = 1500;
            if (!(lis[0].classList.contains('accordion'))) {
                    console.log(lis[5]);
                    [].forEach.call(lis, function(el) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                    el.classList.add('accordion');
                            }, delayOut);
                            delayOut -= 300;
                    });
            } else {
                    [].forEach.call(lis, function(el) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                    el.classList.remove('accordion');
                            }, delayIn);
                            delayIn += 300;
                    });
            }

    };
```

Comment: This question is very vague and the answer is going to be opinionated. What is it you're not happy with exactly, and what is your criteria for success?

Comment: a question for code review? what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply looking to reduce duplication, this might help:

```
var bar = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

bar.onclick = function() {
    var delay = {in: 0, out: 1500};
    var adding = !(lis[0].classList.contains('accordion'));
    [].forEach.call(lis, function(el) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.classList[adding ? 'add' : 'remove']('accordion');
        }, delay[adding ? 'out' : 'in']);
        delay[adding ? 'out' : 'in'] += (adding ? -300 : 300);
    });
};
```

But it does so at some expense in readability.  You'd have to make the call for your codebase as to which seems more maintainable.

In the future, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a good place for code review help.

Comment: absolutely what i was looking for! Thanks a lot Scott!

Comment: On a second look, there might be a little more clean-up that could be achieved.  You don't really need the two-part `delay`, which could be moved down a line and defined as `var delay = adding ? 1500 : 0`, with the lines below simply using `delay` rather than `delay[ ... ]`.  And if you added a `delta` variable initialized to `adding ? -300 : 300`, you could clean up that last line, leaving some pretty readable code.